# (Erlang) extracting public key from certificate in pem format

Tags: erlang, certificate, rsa, public-key, pem

I have a certificate in pem format and I want to extract the public key (RSA). I'm already this far:

```
{ok, PemBin} = file:read_file("/path/to/certificate.pem").
[Certificate] = public_key:pem_decode(PemBin).
```

Now, I can do the following:

```
public_key:pem_entry_decode(Certificate).
```

This gives me a tuple with all sorts of details on the certificate but I can't see anywhere an entry for the public key. How do I get the public key from this certificate? Should be straight forward but I can't find any function in the public_key-module for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, here is the complete function in a module:

```
-module(crypto_helper).
-include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl").
-export([get_public_key_from_cert/1]).

get_public_key_from_cert(PathToCert) ->
   {ok, PemBin} = file:read_file(PathToCert),
   PemEntries = public_key:pem_decode(PemBin),
   {value, CertEntry} = lists:keysearch(‘Certificate’, 1, PemEntries)
   {_, DerCert, _} = CertEntry,
   Decoded = public_key:pkix_decode_cert(DerCert, otp),
   PublicKey = Decoded#'OTPCertificate'.tbsCertificate#'OTPTBSCertificate'.subjectPublicKeyInfo#'OTPSubjectPublicKeyInfo'.subjectPublicKey,
   PublicKey.
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
PublicKey = crypto_helper:get_public_key_from_cert("/usr/admin/myServer/priv/certificate.pem"),
EncryptedMsg = public_key:encrypt_public(<<"Hallo">>, PublicKey),
```

Answer (score 4):

`public_key:pem_entry_decode(Certificate)` returns a `Certificate` record.  To extract the public key from it, you need to load the record definitions.  In the Erlang shell, type the following:

```
rr(public_key).
```

After loading the record definitions into the shell, return values will contain the field names as well as the field values, which should make things a bit clearer.

In an Erlang module, load the header file like this:

```
-include_lib("public_key/include/public_key.hrl").
```

Then you can extract the public key info like this:

```
DecodedCertificate = public_key:pem_entry_decode(Certificate).
DecodedCertificate#'Certificate'.tbsCertificate#'TBSCertificate'.subjectPublicKeyInfo.
```

which returns:

```
#'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{
    algorithm = 
        #'AlgorithmIdentifier'{
            algorithm = {1,2,840,113549,1,1,1},
            parameters = <<5,0>>},
    subjectPublicKey = 
        <<48,130,2,10,2,130,2,1,0,195,76,200,181,90,146,51,183,
          39,91,176,28,95,117,241,28,140,...>>}
```

Or dig down one level further to get the key itself:

```
DecodedCertificate#'Certificate'.tbsCertificate
    #'TBSCertificate'.subjectPublicKeyInfo
    #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'.subjectPublicKey.
<<48,130,2,10,2,130,2,1,0,195,76,200,181,90,146,51,183,39,
  91,176,28,95,117,241,28,140,212,223,132,...>>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. There is only the last step missing where you decode the public key and get the rsa_public_key()-type you have to use in public_key:decrypt_public/2.

Comment: There is a possibility that subjectPublicKey could be 

`{0, KeyDer} = DecodedCertificate#'Certificate'.tbsCertificate
    #'TBSCertificate'.subjectPublicKeyInfo
    #'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'.subjectPublicKey.`

Where KeyDer is Der Encoded, if the key is of type RSA

`RsaPublicKey = public_key:der_decode('RSAPublicKey', KeyDer).`

Now RsaPublicKey is of type rsa_public_key()